# How to input a string (or any type) value to a field for multiple feature layers at once

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, feature-layer, string

I work in ArcMap 10.8.1. I added fields to all of my feature layers using Batch Add Field tool. Now I'm trying to find a way to enter values into those fields. Values are identical for each field.

My way of doing this: open the attribute table of each feature layer and use *Field Calculator* to enter values for all feature records. Close the tab. Open next, use *Field Calculator* and so on.

Is there a way (probably in python) to enter string (or any type) value in the same field in many feature layers at once?

Example: layers "roads", "railroad", "waterways" have a common field called "owner", I need to fill in the value "company X" in all those "owner" fields. Can this be done automatically?

Comment: That comes very close. But the feature layers don't have a common field to be joined by.

Comment: Sure, where "automatically" is defined as "by writing two lines of code" (one is a `for` statement, the other is a "Copy as Python snipped" from the geoprocessing Results log, tweaked with the `for` value).

Comment: I'll try looking into this.